# How to get transaction id in paypal framework in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal framework plugin in wordpress, After I configured plugin, get an error.

```
array (
  'ADDRESSOWNER' => 'PayPal',
  'ADDRESSSTATUS' => 'None',
  'TIMESTAMP' => '2012-01-12T09:39:35Z',
  'CORRELATIONID' => '76e872417bee9',
  'ACK' => 'Failure',
  'VERSION' => '58.0',
  'BUILD' => '2230381',
  'L_ERRORCODE0' => '10011',
  'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Invalid transaction id value',
  'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'A transaction id is required',
  'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => 'Error',
  'PENDINGREASON' => 'None',
  'REASONCODE' => 'None',
)
```

Is there anybody, how I can resolve this error, I sent Invoice id with every form post to paypal. I am using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paypal-framework/

Comment: Can you show your request parameters?

Comment: Thanks but problem has been solved. I used another method to finish my transaction...